# Destructuring assignment. Assign object and it's children in two different variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is a nested object:

```
var a = {
  b: {
   c: 'some value'
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make a destructing assignment to get following two variables with only one statement?

```
var c = 'some value';
var b = {c : {'some value'}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just destructure the two parts separately.

```
var { b, b: { c } } = a;
```

Which compiles to the following code with [Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20%7B%20b%2C%20b%3A%20%7B%20c%20%7D%20%7D%20%3D%20a%3B).

```
var _a = a;
var b = _a.b;
var c = _a.b.c;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
var a = {
  b: {
   c: 'some value'
  }
}

var [c, b] = [a.b.c, a.b]

console.log(c, b)
```